# Help on saving the images

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have the follwoing code to save the image but it seems poor in quality...

is there any way to get the images in a fine quality?

Thanks for any help

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                   self.view.bounds.size.height-50)); 
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -50);    
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(  );
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation( viewImage,0 )];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is a compression quality parameter in `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` function - you set it to the lowest quality (0.0), try to set it to maximum quality value:

```
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation( viewImage,1.0 )];
```

Answer (score 0):

One option as it is mentioned in Vladimir's answer. Another option is you can use the UIImagePNGRepresentation. It will use the PNG format.